# How to give Default Argument of Std::Vector of std::pairs?

Tags: c++, c++14

I don't know how many inputs will come to my function as pair of ints. So in order to achieve that I would like to get a default parameter of std::vector of std::pair, because I want at least one pair in case there is no input. How Can I achieve this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


void default_function(int inp1 = 11, int inp2 = 13){ //, std::vector<std::pair<int,int>> defaultVector = XXXX

}

int main()
{

    default_function();
    return 0;

}
```

For example user can input no pairs in that case I will set them 0,0. They can input (0 , 2) as one pair, or (0 , 5), (2 , 2),(0 , 2) as three or more pairs. How to handle this?

(C++ 14 Version)

Comment: `std::vector<std::pair<int,int>> default_vector = {{0, 0}}`?

Comment: I didnt know how to initalize that, or even possible

Comment: Having a default value for the vector function parameter might not help much as the caller can pass an empty vector to your function. If that is possible you need to check inside the function if the passed vector is empty.

Comment: @MericOzcan I posted an example of the solution that works in ideone. I'll remove it if the first poster makes their comment and answer

Answer (score 2):

Use an initializer list as shown below

```
void default_function(
    std::vector<std::pair<int,int>> v =
    {{1,2}, {3,4}, {5,6}})
{
    for(auto &p: v)
        std::cout << p.first << ", " << p.second << " : ";
}

int main() {
    default_function();
    return 0;
}
```